# C++ Variable number of variadic template parameters

Tags: c++, templates, vector, c++17, variadic-functions

I have the following type alias:

```cpp
using VoidFunc = void (*)();
```

I would like to define a class like so:

```cpp
class SomeClass {
public:

 template<template<typename Return, typename... Args>... Funcs>
 static constexpr typename std::vector<VoidFunc> registerFunctions(Funcs<Return, Args...>... funcs) {
  return { ((VoidFunc)(funcs), ...) };
 }
};
```

I am aware that this is invalid syntax, as `Return` and `Args` are unresolvable outside of their template group. The goal is to allow the function `registerFunction` to accept a variable number of functions all with different prototypes. In the actual implementation, it is important to preserve the type information of each function for use with other `constexpr` functions. Is there a way to achieve this in C++17 or later?

Comment: What're you trying to accomplish with this conversion? Why to `void(*)()`? Also `FunctionReference` is a function pointer, which is a bit confusing.

Comment: @Barry Looks like type erasure. Since conversions between function pointers and object pointers are not required to work by the standard, `void(*)()` is a fair choice.

Comment: @Barry Thanks for pointing that out, the first type alias was not actually relevant to the question and the nomenclature was poor. The question has been updated to reflect this.

Comment: @Quentin The extraneous `constexpr` functions that would branch off from the initial call to `registerFunctions` are not included in the question, however, I did mention that I need to preserve the function prototypes for further use. The use of `std::vector<VoidFunc>` is just a convenient way to store the function pointers.

Comment: @Matthewacon yay, got it right :) -- I don't have time to write an answer right now, but you need to take in a plain `class... Funcs`, using SFINAE to ensure that each of them is indeed a [function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/is_function) [pointer](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/remove_pointer), then disassemble them further once you're handling them one by one (i.e. post-expansion).

Comment: The real question is: what happens after that? What do you need to do with this `std::vector<VoidFunc>` return value and or inside a method/class. Answer to that defines how this could be handled.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You don't actually care about any of those underlying types (at least not in the code presented here). So just don't use it. All you care about is that these things are all function pointers:

```
typename <typename... F>
static std::vector<VoidFunc> registerFunctions(F*... funcs)
{
    static_assert((std::is_function_v<F> && ...));
    return { reinterpret_cast<VoidFunc>(funcs)... };
}
```

If you *do* need the signatures for something else, you can just pass each element of `funcs` into a different function template and just re-deduce the actually signature there.

---

Note that the `typename` is unnecessary there, and the `constexpr` in C++17 makes this ill-formed (since you cannot in C++17 have a `constexpr` `std::vector`).

Comment: how do you deduce the signature once the pointer has been casted to `void(*)()`?

Comment: @fdan You don't - but that's also not what I said.

Comment: Marking the function as `constepxr` with a return type of `std::vector<VoidFunc>` produces the desired result, without compiler errors. Marking the return type as `const` would prevent runtime modifications to the returned value. Is there some hidden undefined behavior that I am missing, resultant of returning a non-literal type from a `constexpr` function?

Comment: @Matthewacon It's [ill-formed, no diagnostic required](http://eel.is/c++draft/dcl.constexpr#5). I also didn't say to make the return type `const` - I said to _not_ make it `constexpr`.

Comment: @Barry Ah okay, you mean he can deduce the signatures in-place, I thought you mean at a later point (because this is what is important to him)

Comment: @Barry The link you posted states that `For a constexpr function or constexpr constructor that is neither defaulted nor a template, if no argument values exist such that an invocation of the function or constructor could be an evaluated subexpression of a core constant expression, or, for a constructor, a constant initializer for some object ([basic.start.static]), the program is ill-formed, no diagnostic required.`. In the question, the function is templated and the return type has a valid list-initialized `constexpr` constructor. So it would not be ill-formed?

Comment: @Barry Also, in the original question, I `const` qualified the function, which is not valid since the function is `static`. Your answer also has this mistake.

Comment: @Matthewacon Read the next section. And fixed, removed the `const`

Comment: @Barry It seems that the code in this answer will compile with GCC 8.2.1 but not with Clang 7.0.1, as `std::vector` is not a literal type and does not contain any `constexpr` constructors.

Comment: @Matthewacon Huh? There is no `constexpr` in my answer. Indeed, I explicitly stated why there is no `constexpr`

Comment: @Barry My mistake, I had not read the updated excerpt that you edited in afterward.